# Is that possible to customize WSL GUI display?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am trying to run a Linux GUI applicaton trough the WSL. Unfortunatly, this app is also quite old and uses its own display system. And its mouse cursor is especially annoying in long use. I don't have any idea if it would be possible to disable to cursor in-app. But is there any way to disable or hide the WSL (or Windows) mouse cursor? I have no idea how Linux GUI applications work on WSL.